# How do you populate a DIV with URL from another domain?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I know it's not possible on the client to fill a DIV with content from another domain. However, I've used the [Google Feeds](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxfeeds/) code and it's pulling information from other domains into a DIV (no iframe) without resorting to server-side code, so I'm assuming somehow it's doable. Thanks.

Comment: How do you know it's not doing anything server-side?

Comment: You're right, it is doing something server-side, as JacobM points out below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>To fill your div with content from a different script, you would need to request the content via ajax and pass the right params along with your request.</strike>

`Edited after @JacobM comment`

You can give [CROSS DOMAIN AJAX: A QUICK SUMMERY](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/cross_domain_aj) a look along with [AJAX Cross Domain Proxy.](http://www.iacons.net/writing/2007/08/02/ajax-cross-domain-proxy/)

Comment: Sure, but browser security prevents this if the script is served on a different domain.

Comment: Can an AJAX call be for a URL from another domain with a query string and get the results as HTML and then fill a DIV with that? If so, is there an example of this? Thanks a million.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't matter if the AJAX call is to a URL that is intended to be a web service or one that's just a regular web page; you can't make AJAX calls to other domains.

Answer (score 7):

From the [F.A.Q.](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxfeeds/faq/#howAccessPublicFeed):

> **If the AJAX Feed API is a JavaScript API, how does it access public feeds
>   without violating the same origin
>   security policy?**
>
> Google.com serves as a proxy to the
>   outside feeds, so your client code
>   only communicates with Google servers.

So, yeah, it's doing something server-side.